# Get ContextMenu when long click on specific item in row in listView

Tags: android, android-listview, android-contextmenu

I use a base adapter to populate a list view, every row of this list has 3 `ImageView`.

I want to show a `ContextMenu` and get the image position when long click on one of those images(not by click on the row of list, but click on image itself), I tried to inflate the `listview` row in the Activity and get the image then register this image for `contextMenu([registerForContextMenu(imgLeft)])` but nothing works.

I thought to call event `onLongClickListener` on every image in the row but I had a problem which is how I can call(show-open) the `contextMenu` in the `baseAdapter`(no Activity here) in method `getView`()...? or how I can register those images for `contextMenu` in the `baseAdapter`...?

I search a lot for solution here and in Google and got nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Registering `ContextMenu` for each ImageView might work. Like this:

```
@Override
public View getView(int arg0, View arg1, ViewGroup arg2) {
    if (arg1 == null) {
        LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) cmx.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        arg1 = vi.inflate(R.layout.services_item, null);
    }
    ImageView serviceThumb = (ImageView) arg1.findViewById(R.id.thumbIView);

    registerForContextMenu(serviceThumb);

    serviceThumb.setOnCreateContextMenuListener(new OnCreateContextMenuListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
            AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo)menuInfo;
            menu.setHeaderTitle("Test");
            for (int i = 0; i< 5; i++) {
                menu.add(Menu.NONE, i, i, i + " - Test");
            }
    }
    });
}
```

Comment: I though about that but I can't get method registerForContextMenu() in the adapter class cause it extends the baseAdapter class not Activity.

Comment: thanks mate. that solved my issue. just the thing is i have to long press the view to open the context menu. is there any other way where i can open context menu on single click. not long press